# Clustering cancer gene expression data at the same time?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm working at gene expression data clustering techniques and I have downloaded 35 datasets from web,
We have 35 datasets that each of them represents a type of cancer. Each dataset has its own features. Some of these datasets are shared in several features, and some of them do not share anything from the viewpoint of features.

My question is, how do we ultimately cluster these data, while many of them do not have the same characteristics?

I think that we do the clustering operation on all 35 datasets at the same time.
Is my idea correct?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: This isn't really the kind of question that is appropriate for StackOverflow as it is too broad. You would be better off talking to colleagues who have done clustering analyses, or researching the topic online—e.g. search PubMed for papers documenting similar studies, search bioinformatics fora, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say heterogenous it'll be things like different gene expression platforms where different genes are present.

You can use any clustering technique, but you'll need to write your own distance metric that takes into account heterogeneity within your dataset. For instance, you could use the correlation of all the genes that are in common between pairwise samples, create a distance matrix from this, then use something like hierarchical clustering on this distance matrix

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to write your own distance metric. There already exists plenty of distance metrics that can work for mixed data types. For instance, the gower distance works well for mixed data type. See this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120928/how-does-the-gower-distance-calculate-the-difference-between-binary-variables) on the same. But if your data contains only continuous values then you can use k-means. You'll also be better off, if the data is preprocessed first.